# Golang MongoDB delete multiple items in one query

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I have a `match` table in my DB and I need to delete multiple items from it and I was wondering if there is a way to do this using a single query.
I get `deleteList` of type `[]primitive.ObjectID` in my Go code. `deleteList` is basically a list of `match.id` that need to be deleted. I could easily do it ranging through my slice of `deleteList` and deleting all the `matches` 1 by 1, but I feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing it in one query instead of flooding my db with multiple queries.

Does anyone know a possible solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share some code that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Collection.DeleteMany()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.DeleteMany).

Construct a filter that matches any of your IDs, and pass that to `DeleteMany()` like this:

```
c := ...                      // acquire match collection
ids := []primitive.ObjectID{} // the id list to delete

filter := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}}

if _, err := c.DeleteMany(ctx, filter); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```